# How do we change language in a Laravel 8 localization?

Tags: php, laravel-8

Wep.php

```
Route::get('language/lang', [Localization::class, "lang_change"])->name('LangChange');
```

controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;


class Localization extends Controller
{
    
      public function lang_change(Request $request)
    {
        App::setLocale($request->lang);
        session()->put('locale', $request->lang);
        return view('profiles');
    }

 }
```

view file

```
       <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="form-control Langchange">
                    <option value="ko" {{ session()->get('locale') == 'ko' ? 'selected' : '' }}>korea</option>
                    <option value="hi" {{ session()->get('locale') == 'hi' ? 'selected' : '' }}>urdu</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          <a href="#">{{__('profiles.Home')}}</a>
          <a href="#">{{__('profiles.Contact')}}</a>
          <a href="#">{{__('profiles.About')}}</a>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "{{ route('LangChange') }}";
    $(".Langchange").language(function(){
        window.location.href = url + "?lang="+ $(this).val();
    });
</script>
```

I'm trying to change the language but nothing happens. And I did create files for different language also just mention where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check this out: [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization).

There is just simple middleware that solves all your problems:

```php
use Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization;

Route::prefix(LaravelLocalization::setLocale())->group(function() {
    // your routes here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. you have to collect the route**

`Route::get('language/{lang}', [Localization::class, "lang_change"])->name('LangChange');`

**2. set your lang_change parameter property**

```
public function lang_change($lang)
{
   App::setLocale($lang);
   session()->put('locale', $lang);
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

**3. Then create a middleware LocalizationMiddleware to handle all the session and add codes in class  handle method**

```
        if(Session::get('locale') != null){
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        } else {
            Session::put('locale','en');
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        }
```